# Can this Python script be made in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, integration, translate

I'm very new to computer programming, and me and some friends are making a small project that chooses a random line of text from a text file full of data. I have a `Python` script that chooses a random line of a text file and returns it.

```
import random

filePath = "../data/strats.txt"
count = len(open(filePath).readlines(  ))
lineNum = randint(1, count)
lines = [0]
with open(filePath) as strats:
while strats.readline():
        lines.append(strats.tell())
    strats.seek(lines[lineNum])
    line = strats.readline()
return line
```

This connects to some `JavaScript` code, but I'm having trouble using the python script without a web server. I would like to make the website all client side, and that means making this same program in `JavaScript`. If there is another way, please let me know. Otherwise: **Can this `Python` script be translated into `JavaScript`?**

Comment: yes you can, up to the extend that you'll have the exact same trouble if you want to use it without a web server.. Javascript is limited in term of client files access (for security reasons)

Comment: By the way i'm wondering, how do you expect to make a "all client side website" without any server? A single page application maybe, but not a whole website (i am conscious this is maybe not a very precise terminology, but i think you see what i mean)

Comment: Yeah, it is just one page. It is just a small school assignment. I'm just trying to make it a little fancier.

Comment: Perhaps if there was a way to index a txt file line by line, maybe turn it into JSON, I could abandon the python code entirely. `{"1": "Line 1 of a txt file", "2": "Line 2 of a txt file"}` would be how it looks? Maybe I could request the file with `ajax` and add a function to it that would choose a random line from the text file. Or just write the file in JSON. Just random ideas, I don't really know how I would do all of these.